# Register tech startup as a legal business

Tags: software, business, corporate-law, new-york-state

Right now I have an an uber like website ready to be launched: you can sign up to be someone who provides a service or someone who uses the service. I am trying to integrate payment using things like Paypals Braintree or Stripe. I see that to do this I need to be registered as a legal entity. I really do not know anything about how to do this. Right now this is a one person company with plans to hire in the future if things go well. Any advice as to if I really need to register the business, what kind of business to register as, how to go about this, etc. would be greatly appreciated. By the way I am in New York if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Find a lawyer in NY who specializes in business startups to help you with your questions. You're opening yourself up to considerable liability with an App and a service open to the general public and deals with financial transactions, and you need sound legal advice. (At very least use https://www.legalzoom.com/ to start to find out what you need to do with your business venture and consider your options.)

I.e., among other things (which a lawyer can explain): you need a strong TOS drafted for the App and service that covers all the legal bases; you need to find out how to protect yourself personally and professionally from liability, possibly with a corporation; you need to protect your Intellectual Property (IP) that is built into the App; you need advice on how to be compliant with many state and federal laws regarding financials, licenses and business registrations; and you need to be sure your legal decisions allow for company growth.

And you need a lawyer to tailor all those points to your specific situation. You're not reinventing the wheel, but your business and legal situation will be different than others, so you need real legal advice.